# Visual Studio 2017 "Cannot determine the project containing the file <filename>.java"

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2017

I've a solution containing two project types `.androidproj` (Android) and `.vcxproj` (C++) in my Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. When I open one of my java files in the Android project in Visual Studio I see the message `Cannot determine the project containing the file <filename>.java` with a leading exclamation mark icon.

[image: Cannot determine project]

The message does not make sense to me. The file is clearly seen in the Solution Explorer and also present in the project file (`.androidproj`) itself as:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaCompile Include="src\<filename>.java" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Any hint where this message may come from and how to get rid of it?

My System is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.2 (26430.6) Release

Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
```

**Update**

Does it happen with one specific .java file or with all of them?

- It does happen to all the files of the project.

Have you tried re-creating the project from scratch and manually adding the files?

- No. But the same project does work on a colleagues machine.

Do other Android projects work fine?

- Yes, other Android project work (just created a new default one).

**Update2**

May this information is helpful to solve the issue. In order to use Java Code syntax and semantic colorization, semantic highlighting, error and warning squiggles as well as auto-completion in Visual Studio 2017 I installed the extension "[Java Language Service for Android and Eclipse Android Project Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.JavaLanguageServiceforAndroidandEclipseAndroidProj)" from Microsoft.

**Update 3**

Disabling the extension "[Java Language Service for Android and Eclipse Android Project Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.JavaLanguageServiceforAndroidandEclipseAndroidProj)" lets the message disappear. But the drawback is that the `.java` file is not recognized anymore. On re-enabling the extension the message comes back as well.
Uninstalling and re-installing didn't help either.

**Update 4**

The version mentioned in the solution file matches the main Visual Studio version I've installed. The solution contains:

```
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26430.6
```

Comment: A couple of questions: does it happen with one specific .java file or with all of them? Have you tried re-creating the project from scratch and manually adding the files? Do other Android projects work fine?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see my answers in the question - Update.

Comment: I guess disabling the extension did no good, right?

Comment: @EmilioVicari nope, also re-installing didn't help.

Comment: Could it be a versioning mismatch problem (the project targets another _VStudio_ version: e.g. 2015)?

Comment: @CristiFati thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately no, the version of the solution matches Visual Studio 2017

Comment: What were your colleagues computer specs + Visual Studio version @BrunoBieri?

Comment: @Jouster500 my collegues computer specs are: Win10 with the exact same version of Visual Studio. We also compared the installed components of Visual Studio and they are the same too.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Could it be possible that one of your libraries doesn't have all necessary components? As you know, Java and C++ have a lot of user created libraries. Some prominent examples include things like boost or libcurl but need to be built on your machine before being used. It could be possible that your friend had a correctly configured library of these items which allowed your program to be built on their machine as opposed to yours. This may be irrelevant, but a lot of software can behave in unpredictable ways. Like a bus error that gets thrown for commenting a `cout` statement. =P

Comment: @Jouster500 thank you for your response. I'm checking the libraries used in my project. I'll update my question with the results once I checked the libraries.